# npm install fails on Mac OX El capitan

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting this error message:

> Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: inotify@1.4.1

launching this command:

```
npm install semantic-ui-sass --save=dev
```

I found on github one similar issue and they have recommended an nodeJS upgrade, but i did it and got still failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not `--save=dev`, it should be `--save-dev`

Comment: but when i test with equal sign i get exactly this error on El Capitan. so edit you question and i delete this answer as its useless.

Comment: Uhms, seems like i got it. I dont know how but i launch it another time and it works.